# udp socket receive buffer size

Tags: java, sockets, networking, netty

I am use Netty ( a java network framework) to server UDP request .

I found the

> SO_RCVBUF

and

> /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default

and

> /proc/net/udp

output confusing:

By the manual of socket( man 7 socket) It explains :

> rmem_default
>                 contains the default setting in bytes of the socket receive
>                 buffer.
>
> rmem_max
>                 contains the maximum socket receive buffer size in bytes which
>                 a user may set by using the SO_RCVBUF socket option.

and the /proc/net/udp show's the udp receive queue size :

```
 sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue          rx_queue    tr         tm->when   retrnsmt uid     timeout inode                                           
 60: 00000000:2F3C 00000000:0000 07 00000000:0003E094 00:00000000 00000000   500        0        2224362 2       ffff810066908cc0
```

I can get the **SO_RCVBUF** = 12904, but the **rx_queue** size is 254100(3E094), and **rmem_default** is 262142

my confuse is, why the SO_RCVBUF not equals to the rmem_default, and why the queue size not equals the SO_RCVBUF (but larger than it ) ?

It seams the `ctx.channel().config().getOption(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF)`'s value is half of `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default` and the real receive buffer size( queue size ) is also the value of `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default`

so why `ctx.channel().config().getOption(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF)` not equals to the system's config ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You seem to have misread the output. When you line up the columns properly, `rx_queue` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is wrong. The correct alignment is:

```
tx_queue rx_queue
00000000:0003E094
```

So `rx_queue` is `0x0003E094` or `254100`. This can be confirmed using `netstat -unlp | grep pid` , `Recv-Q` is second column. Example output:

```
cat /proc/net/udp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops             
 8101: 41FD080A:06A5 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00005A00 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 3892411 2 0000000000000000 0 

netstat --udp -nl
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
udp    23040      0 10.8.253.65:1701        0.0.0.0:*
```

Here, `0x00005A00`==`23040`